# Using Google Sign-In to keep track of user's free quota - what if user disconnects account?

Tags: android, google-signin, privacy

My Android app gives users a free monthly quota for the service provided. Users are required to sign in with Google to keep track of the quota.

Now the documentation for Google Sign-In states [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect)

> It is highly recommended that you provide users that signed in with Google the ability to disconnect their Google account from your app. If the user deletes their account, you must delete the information that your app obtained from the Google APIs.

and [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#revokeAccess()) even:

> Applications are required to provide users that are signed in with Google the ability ...

But if I delete the record with the user's quota usage, a user could always simply disconnect his account and sign in again to get new free quotas.

Would it be against Google's terms if I state in the privacy policy and terms of service that a record about the quota-usage is kept even if the account is disconnected?

Does someone have another idea?

Comment: I don't think that storing any user's app/game related data would go against any policies.

Comment: well, "information that your app obtained from the Google APIs" includes the account-ID, and I would have to keep that (or the email address).

Comment: Aahh alright, I completely missed that part. You can explain / declare that in your app's privacy policy & there should not be any problem.